# Kubuntu slows down over time until it becomes unresponsive since update on 23.04

Tags: linux, firefox, kde, kubuntu, unresponsive

I am running Kubuntu 23.04 and have recently updated from 22.10. Ever since I am experiencing an issue that happens regularily although I cannot make out a clear pattern like after what time or if a certain software is running. It seems to happen more often after sleep mode but that is it. It manifests like this

- the ui becomes slower and slower
- first I recognize a stuttery movement of the mouse
- UI elements take longer to react (all applications)
- after a while responsiveness has become so bad that the OS esentially froze completely

Unfortunately there is not much to go from. dmseg and journalctl do not really show much that is suspicious except from the following Firefox entries (and sometimes it seems like mouse movement becomes more laggy after starting firefox however the issue also persists without using firefox)

*dmesg*

```
[  266.184701] kauditd_printk_skb: 129 callbacks suppressed
[  266.184704] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202281.808:143): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4489 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  266.184708] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202281.808:144): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19361/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4489 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  266.417077] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.040:145): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=4531 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.417119] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.040:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=4531 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.417309] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.040:147): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=4531 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  266.986627] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.608:148): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=4592 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  266.986834] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.608:149): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=4592 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  266.986867] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.608:150): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=4592 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  266.986925] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.608:151): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=4592 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  266.987006] audit: type=1400 audit(1686202282.608:152): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=4592 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

I guess without more information it is hard to pin down the problem so the first question would be where else could I look to identify the problem?

Comment: Seen the same problem